# Branching Processes - piecewise function

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, generating-functions, markov-process, branching-rules

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ be a branching process, where $X_0=1$

Given $\mathbb{P}(Z=z)= \begin{cases} a & z=0 \\ b & z=1\\ c &z=2 \end{cases}$, where $a,b,c \in (0,1)$ , $a+b+c=1$ and $c<a$

My Attempt:

$G(S) = \mathbb{E}(s^Z) = \sum_{s=0}^\infty s^Z\mathbb{P}(Z=z)=s $

$=a+bs+cs^2=s$

$=a+(b-1)s+cs^2=0$

Then, I know that $s=1$ is a solution. How do I find a,b, and c for the other solution / an equation for them?

Or have I misunderstood what to do?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How do I find the values of a, b, and c

Comment: The values of $a$, $b$, and $c$...given what, exactly? The only conditions I see are that these numbers lie in $(0,1)$, sum to $1$, and $c<a$. There are of course uncountably many such possibilities.